# How does setMaxStreams in SoundPool work?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer, soundpool

In a video I was watching about `SoundPool`, it mentioned setMaxStreams. The streamer said that setMaxStreams allows `SoundPool` to dedicate a portion of memory to each stream and set them up before it's even used.

This confused me since the name 'setMaxStreams' implies that this attribute limits the number of streams that can be played in a `SoundPool`. I checked the docs, and it said the same thing.

So does `SoundPool`'s setMaxStreams prepare the streams ahead of time and limit the max number of streams?

Thanks!

Comment: Also posted here: https://coderanch.com/t/741940/mobile/setMaxStreams-SoundPool-work#3447593

Comment: Yeah, that's by me. Just trying to get an answer. Thanks.

Comment: always best to mention that you have post-posted to other sites so that others no waste their time responding to questions which have already been answered elsewhere. :-)

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. Thank you for your response!